# Declare path parameters in Jersey programmatically

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to create jersey resources programatically (without Annotations).
I have a method raiseAlarm that takes a Name and id as input parameter. I want to take Name from the JSON input and I want id to come from path parameter. The code looks some thing like this...

```java
public class JerseyExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JerseyExample deployer = new JerseyExample();
        deployer.init();
    }

    public static class BaseResource extends ResourceConfig
    {
        public BaseResource()
        {
            init();
        }

        public void init()
        {
            try
            {
                Resource.Builder resourceBuilder2 = Resource.builder();
                resourceBuilder2.path("/raiseAlarm/{id}");
                ResourceMethod.Builder method2 = resourceBuilder2.addMethod("POST")
                    .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .handledBy(this,
                        this.getClass().getMethod("raiseAlarm", Name.class, String.class));

                Resource childResource1 = resourceBuilder2.build();

                Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder();
                resourceBuilder.path("/employee/status");
                resourceBuilder.addChildResource(childResource1);
                Resource rootResource = resourceBuilder.build();
                registerResources(rootResource);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String raiseAlarm(Name notification, @PathParam("id") String id)
        {
            System.out.println("INSIDE RAISE ALARM ");
            System.out.println(notification.toString() + " ID: " + id);
            return "Result";
        }

        public void destroy()
        {

        }

        public static class Name
        {

            String firstName;

            String lastName;

            String middleName;

            public String getFirstName()
            {
                return firstName;
            }

            public void setFirstName(String firstName)
            {
                this.firstName = firstName;
            }

            public String getLastName()
            {
                return lastName;
            }

            public void setLastName(String lastName)
            {
                this.lastName = lastName;
            }

            public String getMiddleName()
            {
                return middleName;
            }

            public void setMiddleName(String middleName)
            {
                this.middleName = middleName;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName;
            }
        }
    }

    public void init()
    {

        Server server = new Server();

        ServletContextHandler context0 =
            new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        ServletHolder serveltHolder1 =
            new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(new BaseResource()));

        context0.addServlet(serveltHolder1, "/*");
        context0.setVirtualHosts(new String[] {"@external"});
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setHost("localhost");
        connector.setPort(9069);
        connector.setName("external");

        HandlerCollection collection = new HandlerCollection();
        collection.addHandler(context0);
        server.setHandler(collection);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        try
        {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works.
I want to know a way in which I can declare the Path paramenters or Query parameters programatically, so that I can define my method signature as raiseAlarm(Name notification,String id) and avoid @PathParam("id") annotation.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out on this? I want to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been asked a while ago, but I had the same issue and found the answer. See my question and own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598437/path-parameter-in-programmatic-jersey-resource) for the complete code.

You have to add a child resource with a *path* in the same manner as the `@Path` annotation. After that, you can get at the path parameter through the `getUriInfo()` method of the context.

Like this (assuming you already have a `Resource.Builder` object):

```java
final Resource.Builder subResourceBuilder = resourceBuilder.addChildResource("{id}");

subResourceBuilder.addMethod("GET")
    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, Response>() {

    @Override
    public Response apply(ContainerRequestContext rctx) {
         // Get to the path parameter                    
         MultivaluedMap<String, String> pparams = rctx.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
         List<String> idValues = pparams.get("id");
         // Create response here
    }
});
```