# Path parameter in programmatic Jersey resource

Tags: java, jersey

I am using Jersey's programmatic API described [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html) to dynamically create configured resources from a configuration file at runtime. 
My code to create those resources follows these lines:

```
public ResourceCreator() {
    for (String resource : cfg.getConfiguredResources())
    {
        logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "Creating resource {0}", resource);

        final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder()
            .path(resource);

        resourceBuilder.addMethod("GET")
                .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, Response>() {

            @Override
            public Response apply(ContainerRequestContext rctx) {
                // Create response here
            }
        });
        final Resource resourceObj = resourceBuilder.build();
        registerResources(resourceObj);
    }

}
```

This works fine, however the next step is to *programmatically* provide subresources (child resources?) with a Path parameter. Normally I would annotate these with

```
@GET
@Path( "/{id}" )
@Produces( { "application/json" } )
public Response processIdGet( @PathParam( "id" ) String id ...)
```

now - **how do I do this programmatically?**

The Jersey documentation regarding the programmatic API is very concise to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know how you start seeing the solution after you've asked the question?

It turns out I have to add a child resource with a *path* in the same manner as the `@Path` annotation. After that, I can get at the path parameter through the `getUriInfo()` method of the context.

Like this:

```
final Resource.Builder subResourceBuilder = resourceBuilder.addChildResource("{id}");

subResourceBuilder.addMethod("GET")
    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    .handledBy(new Inflector<ContainerRequestContext, Response>() {

    @Override
    public Response apply(ContainerRequestContext rctx) {
         // Get to the path parameter                    
         MultivaluedMap<String, String> pparams = rctx.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
         List<String> idValues = pparams.get("id");
         // Create response here
    }
});
```

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution but the only difference is that I have add HeaderParam and QueryParam into my dyncamically generated resource

Comment: I tried your example  and I am getting a null on the context. Have you experienced that ?

Comment: @kimathie do you mean the context in `apply(ContainerRequestContext rctx)` is `null` so `rctx.getUriInfo()` result in a nullpointerexception? That should be handled by Jersey IMHO.

Comment: yes, but I could be doing something wrong. here is my question in relation to that issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70646059/how-to-correctly-configure-resources-with-jersey-programmatically